# Inconsistent accessibility error with the following c# code. Why?

Tags: c#

Whats wrong with the following c# code? Compiler reports this error:

Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ClassLibrary1.Interface1' is less accessible than method 'ClassLibrary1.Class1.Class1(ClassLibrary1.Interface1)'

with the following code:

```
interface Interface1<T>
{
    bool IsDataValid();
    /* Other interfaces */
}

public class Class1<T>
{
    public Interface1<T> interface1;

    public Class1(Interface1<T> interface1)
    {
        this.interface1 = interface1;
    }

}
```

I've since designed my code differently using inheritence to but if anyone could tell me what the above is wrong I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

your "Interface1" isn't public..

```
public interface Interface1<T>
{
    bool IsDataValid();
    /* Other interfaces */
}
```

Comment: doh. Thankyou. That was so obvious I feel embarrassed. Funny sometimes how you fail to see the blindingly obvious.

Comment: In VS2010, I added the public after creating the class and had to clean the project to get rid of this error.

Comment: IDE could have had a more explicit message, honestly

Answer (score 6):

Mark your interface as public:

`public interface Interface1<T>`

If you leave out the accessibility label, it defaults to `internal`, that is, only accessible to other classes within the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

second solution is If your interface is not public then dont make your class public where you are making a handle of interface.