# Inconsistent Accessibility

Tags: c#

I have taken a simple interface

```
public interface IBinaryHelper
{
    toBinary ConvertToBinary(string pathBinary);
}
```

I am trying access is in a class below it

```
public class ApiHelper : IBinaryHelper
{
    private readonly RestClient _client;

    public toBinary ConvertToBinary(string pathBinary)
    {
        toBinary binary = null;
        var request = new RestRequest("SampleAPI/ConvertToBinary/{pathBinary}", Method.GET) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
        request.AddParameter("pathBinary", pathBinary, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        var response = _client.Execute<toBinary>(request);
        binary = response.Data;
        return binary;
    }
}
```

Now when build it, this is the error am getting an error Inconsisten accessibility:

> Return type `ApiHelper.toBinary` is less accessible than method `ApiHelper.ApiHelper.ConvertToBinary(string)` at `ConvertToBinary` method both in interface and in the class

Comment: It's complaining that the type `toBinary` is not public. You can't return a private or internal type from a public method (obvious if you think about it)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inconsistent accessibility error with the following c# code. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524761/inconsistent-accessibility-error-with-the-following-c-sharp-code-why)

Comment: Please make sure to link error details from MSDN (assuming you've already read the article that is available by clicking F1 on error message) and explaining what is not clear there. Also sample should show information reported in the error - in the post declaration of `toBinary` is not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an object of type `toBinary` from a public method on a public class.

The `toBinary` class needs to be visible to all possible callers of the `ApiHelper.ConvertToBinary` method - therefore, it should be public as well.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, the inconsistency is not by calling that method, but `toBinary` is apparently a class that is not `public`. You cannot offer a method as `public`, if one cannot access the return type publicly.

Apparently your `toBinary` `class`/`interface`/`struct`/... is `internal`, `private`, inner class,... You should make this public as well.

Another hint: the names of classes start in general with an uppercase character. So it should be `ToBinary` not `toBinary`.